# .Net MVC Actionlink using %20 instead of + in querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string

I'm using actionlinks in various places to create links in my mvc 4 app. Ive noticed that querystring parameters with spaces get the %20 treatment, which is fine, but other parts of my app use a form with action=get to pass querystrings with + encoding for the spaces. In the interest of keeping things consistent, can I have the actionlink use this same + encoding on the qs?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` in your ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Foo","Home", new {title= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("hello world")}, null)
```

Meanwhile on the other hand, you should use `HtmlDecode`.